# How to bulk rename files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with 100+ files, and all of them have a common format, namely one string, followed by 4-digit number specifying year, and then at the end just a single lowercase letter. For example, one valid file would be Test2012b

Now, I want to rename them in such a way that the last year and letter part come to beginning inside the brackets, and then the string at the beginning go to end. My above example filename Test2012b would be renamed to [2012b]Test

I though about just using Rename-Item of PowerShell as below, but I really don't know how can I make the above filename transformation. Any ideas?

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf| Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ???? }
```

Comment: Anything you have tried or considered? There are oodles of questions like this one. You already know how to rename the file but need to work on manipulating the string. You already know you want the last X characters so looking for something like that will get you your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "(\w+?)(\d+)(\w)", '[$2$3]$1' }
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer @t1meless solution but it's an other solution

```
gci *.pdf| rni -NewName {"[{0}]{1}.pdf" -f $_.BaseName.Substring($_.BaseName.Length -5, 5), $_.BaseName.Substring(0, $_.BaseName.Length -5)}
```